# What if skull island from king kong exist

Tags: internal-consistency

I've been wondering on whether skull island from king kong could exist or not. Like for example could the creatures on be possible, could dinosaurs survive to here, what are the natives culture, language, beliefs, and traditions. If some of you have an answer let me know.

Comment: Is everyone there to answer this

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please note that the Worldbuilding SE is dedicated to providing detailed answers to specific questions about your world. It is not -- and should not be -- our responsibility to create your world for you. If you have a specific problem you need help with, feel free to ask another question to address it.

Answer (score 1):

On our Earth, as it is now, no - we'd have discovered it long ago.

But if the question is *could* such an island have existed - maybe. There are several versions of Skull Island in different versions of King Kong.

There's enough information in the World of Kong book tie-in to the 2005 movie to show that that version can't work - it's far too small.

Large animals can live on rather small islands, such as moose on Isle Royale, but Skull Island 2005 is far *too* small. It is tropical, so no winter forage crunch (on the other hand, moist tropical vegetation often has a lot of chemical defenses and isn't as much of a herbivore buffet as it looks). Even so, the World of Kong map shows it less than 10 miles in longest dimension - and very cut up by sea inlets and rocky uplands so the amount of good productive land will be very small. It would be very questionable even for supporting moose-size herbivores... there's absolutely no way it could support 100-foot-long sauropods and T-rex sized (or slightly larger) carnivores.

However, a more limited version - a tropical island supporting a giant ape and some big, freaky reptiles (though not actual dinosaurs - how are they going to survive the end-Cretaceous extinction?) - is probably possible.

*Gigantopithecus* lived in Southeast Asia. It was a giant ape, though far smaller than Kong (about 3 meters/10 feet). Your best bet would be isolating some on a Southeast Asia/Australasia island big enough for them to evolve larger size, up to the low-end range of Kong's very variable size in the films.

In Pleistocene Australia, there were some big reptiles like *Megalania* (a super-monitor lizard) and big python/boa like madtsoiid snakes. Wouldn't be far to raft some over...

Comment: Dwarfism tends to set in with large animals living on islands. Small islands especially so. Skull Island might support puppy sized sauropods & chicken sized T-Rexs. And Kong would be a dwarf giant ape. So Gigantopithecus is a plausible King. of course, Skull island might be an island continent in a parallel universe accessible by wormhole, just sail through it, and the problems disappear.

Comment: Island dwarfism is a thing... but possibly not that extreme. And it's not instant - Wrangel Island had "dwarf" mammoths (still pretty huge, ~2 meters at the shoulder) after mammoths went extinct

Comment: Oops... accidentally hit enter & it timed out. Komodo dragons live on a tiny island, and the known Mesozoic island-dwarf sauropods  (Europasaurus, Magyarosaurus) were cow-to-small-rhino size not puppy size. Also, a "real" Skull Island would probably be part of the Sunda Shelf, only made into an island by rising seas at the end of the last Ice Age, so the dwarfing might not be complete. And there are 'island giants' too like the giant moa of New Zealand and elephant bird of Madagascar.

Comment: I mentioned island dwarfism as one of the ways reality often confounds our expectations. Interested to hear about dwarf sauropods. No it wouldn't be an instant effect. Though if Skull Island had dinosaurs they would have been for a long time. Many tens of megayears. But dwarf dinosaurs would make a Gigantopithecus fighting them more plausible. Thanks for the feedback. It torpedoed some of my ideas, but gave lots of new knowledge and things to think about. Much appreciated.